# update existing table column based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write SQL query for following table,

Employee

```
id | name   | batch |certificate_name | flag
---------------------------------------
  1| stefan | a     | java            | null
  2| ross   | b     | c++             | null
  3| mad    | a     | php             | null
```

Query is, for each row check occurrences of certificate and if certificate occurs once in table and batch is 'a' then make flag 1 else do nothing

Result should be:

```
id | name   | batch |certificate_name | flag
---------------------------------------
  1| stefan | a     |java             | 1
  2| ross   | b     |c++              | null
  3| mad    | a     |php              | 1
```

what I tried is following,

```
update employee set flag = 1 
where batch = 'a' 
-- how to write sql query condition for check current row certificate occurrence in table
and ???
```

Comment: `update ... set ... where ...`

Comment: trying to make it db independent but currently using mysql

Comment: what do you mean by "occurs once in a table"? Are you only flagging the first occurrence? Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: I know example is bit stupid but just want to know how to achieve it in sql and as your question answer "not first occurrence but only one occurrence in table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first build a list of unique certificates.

```
SELECT certificate_name FROM Employee GROUP BY certificate_name HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Next I would use that when doing an update.

```
UPDATE Employee
SET flag = 1
WHERE batch = 'a'
 and certificate_name IN (SELECT certificate_name FROM Employee GROUP BY certificate_name HAVING count(*) = 1);
```

Comment: you made it, Thanks

Comment: For mysql somehow i have to add extra "select * from " in IN(....) and have to use SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;